# CListCtrl (MFC) selection click passes through to control UNDERNEATH the list

Tags: mfc, click, controls, clistctrl

My CListCtrl (Report View, single column) ignores item selection when there's another control behind the CListCtrl.  It's as if the click passes through to the control BEHIND the CListCtrl.

Selection is fine if the list item isn't on top of another dialog-box item.

It's baffling because the CListCtrl's z order is ABOVE these other controls.  Can anyone suggest something I could try to make the CListCtrl accept a click even when there's another overlapped control?  Thanks!

Comment: Is your CListCtrl transparent? Does it have `LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT` style? Do you click on the item or next to it? What control is behind?

Comment: It's not transparent, and the suggested style had no effect.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

User Spy++ to check the message flow. And to check if another control is above your control! Maybe there is something wrong with you´r z-order even if you think that the control is above. Also check if you overwrote WM_NCHITTEST